# Заливка текстурой через SKShader

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, spritekit

Имеется `SKShapeNode`, необходимо залить его повторяющейся текстурой. Пробовал делать это через `fillTexture`, но этот способ не работает из-за того что берется текстура и растягивается на весь `SKShapeNode`, мне же надо что бы заливка была с повторением текстуры в оригинальном размере.

Я так понимаю это можно сделать через `fillShader` - создать шейдер с текстурой и залить им `SKShapeNode`. Но тут возникает проблема что я никогда не работал с графикой и понятия не имею как правильно создавать шейдеры.

Может кто помочь с этим?

Comment: Если вопрос решен, то отметьте принятый ответ галкой. Не нужно дописывать это в название вопроса )

Comment: @Kromster свой ответ могу отмечать только через 24 часа..

Comment: Так даже лучше. Может быть вам кто-то подскажет ответ лучше или правильнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось углубится в тему в которой я никогда не работал, но тем не менее сделал свой шейдер по заливке текстурой нода, работает именно так как и надо. Может кому пригодится:

```
void main() {

    // shape_size - размер нода в пикселях
    // texture_size - размер текстуры в пискселях
    // new_texture - нужная текстура

    // Зум текстуры
    float scale = 0.5;

    // Вычисление данных
    vec2 countFill = shape_size.xy / texture_size.xy; // Сколько раз текстура помещается в ноде
    vec2 textSize = (texture_size.xy / shape_size.xy) * countFill.xy; // Размер в зависимости от пропорций
    vec2 coord = v_tex_coord.xy; // Текущая точка

    // Вычисления кординат текстуры
    coord.xy = (coord.xy * countFill.xy) * scale;

    // Дублирование текстуры по X
    if(textSize.x < coord.x){
        int count = coord.x / textSize.x;
        coord.x = coord.x - (textSize.x * count);
    }
    // Дублирование текстуры по Y
    if(textSize.y < coord.y){
        int count = coord.y / textSize.y;
        coord.y = coord.y - (textSize.y * count);
    }

    // Создание и добавление точки
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(new_texture, coord);
    gl_FragColor = texColor;
}
```